# The tag handler query does not have a setter for the attribute ormOptions specified in the Tag Library Descriptor

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

A friend is receiving an error on two CFM's running on a CF 9 server. There error states:

> The tag handler query does not have a setter for the attribute
>   ormOptions specified in the Tag Library Descriptor

A quick Google turns up 19 results. Most are unanswered questions, the others say re-install CF 9. I would prefer to offer an option other than re install if at all possible.

I've tried a reboot. Other than that, I have no idea where to go. When Google doesn't know, how can I be expected to?

Note: I'm told that nothing has changed on the server. The SQL contents of a `cfquery` tag were modified. In addition, the web application is not using ORM at all.

Any thoughts on where to start?

---

**Stack Trace**

```
coldfusion.jsp.JRunTagLibraryInfo$NoSuchAttributeException: The tag handler query does not have a setter for the attribute ormOptions specified in the Tag Library Descriptor.
    at coldfusion.jsp.JRunTagLibraryInfo.getPropertyType(JRunTagLibraryInfo.java:627)
    at coldfusion.jsp.JRunTagLibraryInfo.buildTagInfo(JRunTagLibraryInfo.java:585)
    at coldfusion.jsp.JRunTagLibraryInfo.getTag(JRunTagLibraryInfo.java:267)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslationContext.findTagName(NeoTranslationContext.java:346)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslationContext.isKnownTag(NeoTranslationContext.java:222)
    at coldfusion.compiler.SemanticAnalyzer.preTransformCftag(SemanticAnalyzer.java:461)
    at coldfusion.compiler.SemanticAnalyzer.preTransform(SemanticAnalyzer.java:46)
    at coldfusion.compiler.Treewalker.postorder(Treewalker.java:21)
    at coldfusion.compiler.Treewalker.postorder(Treewalker.java:27)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parseAndTransform(NeoTranslator.java:416)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:343)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:144)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache$1.fetch(TemplateClassLoader.java:418)
    at coldfusion.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:180)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache.fetchSerial(TemplateClassLoader.java:362)
    at coldfusion.util.AbstractCache.fetch(AbstractCache.java:58)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.findClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:591)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:80)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: Without more to go on this is a complete shot in the dark, but .. did you recently update? A quick search turned up [this thread](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:62780#343284) which suggests clearing the cfclasses cache might help.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `cfquery` tag in question (that was modified)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say the server is 9.0 and not 9.0.1. `ormOptions` was introduced in 9.0.1 ([according to the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html)).

It's always helpful, btw, if you're asking about an error in some code, to:
a) post the code;
b) post the exact error, exactly as it is on the screen (with robust exception handling switched on).

This saves having to guess / assume things about your situation.

Comment: You're correct in saying that's it's a 9.0 server. `9.0.0.251028' to be exact. The error is exactly what I stated. No additional information is provided. I can post the stacktrace if you wish. I'm confused though, why an error relating to ormOptions when it doesn't exist in 9.0?

Comment: Well the actual error will also have line numbers and be singling out the code it's complaining about, yes? `ormOptions` doesn't exist in 9.0, no. But by the sounds of it it *does* exist in the code (which you still haven't posted, btw). Did you apply a hotfix intended for 9.0.1 or 9.0.2 to this box? That might cause it maybe?

Comment: Adam, It's been a year or so since I've done CF development, but I have done it for year. There is no line number, there is no template name, there is simply the message that I posted and the stack trace. There is **no** `ormOptions` in the code.

Comment: Yeah, reading up on it more, it sounds like it's a glitch in the 9.0.1 updater that occurs for some people. Are you *certain* no-one's tried to put the 9.0.1 or 9.0.2 updater on, or accidentally installed a hotfix intended for either of those on the server? Did you try to patch that recent security hole in CF (http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix-apsb13-03.html), and put the 9.0.1 on instead of the 9.0 one?

Comment: Also where are you seeing this error? On the screen or in a log file? Am very bemused you're not getting more info than that. Do you have robust exception handling switched on?

Comment: And did you clear the cfclasses dir's files out as per @Leigh's suggestion? That has fixed this for one person.

Comment: OK, so I talked to my friend again. When I told him that `ormOptions` was a 9.01 feature, he remembered that he had tried to install 9.01 without success a while back. I instructed him to re-install and if fixed the issue. Thanks for working through this with me.

Comment: Cool. Have you checked, btw, that they have done *something* about that security hole I mentioned? It's unrelated to your question, but if your mate ain't that au fait with CFAdmin, he might not know about that situation. It really does need to be patched on all live servers.